maximization of function with constraints
let us consider following code :
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def  obj(x):
    x1 =x[0]
    x2 =x[1]
    x3 =x[2]
    return (x1*1000+x2*1000+x3*500)

def constr(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    x3 = x[2]
    return 150-(x1+x2+x3)

bound_x1 =(0,None)
bound_x2 =(0,None)
bound_x3 =(0,None)
const_form ={"type":"ineq","fun":constr}
x0 =[0,0,0]
result =minimize(obj,x0,method ='SLSQP',constraints=const_form,bounds=[bound_x1,bound_x2,bound_x3])
print(result['x'])
print(result)

this problem is taken from the following  site :Optimization
i want  to maximize, if i run this program , result is :

minimization works pretty fine, but i want maximization, based on  a little research, i have  updated code like this :
def  obj(x,sign=-1.0):
    x1 =x[0]
    x2 =x[1]
    x3 =x[2]
    return (x1*1000+x2*1000+x3*500)*sign

and got following output :

based on website, the answer should be :

is there anything missed in my code?

there is nothing wrong, any answer with x1 + x2 = 150 is correct .... they all have the same profit.

how can i change if  i want nonzero solutions?

then don't have a question with a possible zero solution ... like adding another constraint to make the zero not a solution.

It seems, you are not looking for minimization but for linear programming where constraints on item quantities drive the solution. Is that correct?

Reading the article, the problem seems to be ill posed. At least it's clear that any combination x1 + x2 = 150 will give the same total profit. Difference between solvers is implementation details and initial guess.

The ambiguity of the output aside, your implementation is incorrect. In context, 'Units' must be integral, and the system is linear:
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import milp, LinearConstraint, Bounds

df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.Index(name='Products', data=('TV Set', 'Stereo', 'Speakers')),
    data={
        'Sale Price': (5000, 3000, 2000),
        'Cost per Unit': (4000, 2000, 1500),
    },
)
df['Profit per Unit'] = df['Sale Price'] - df['Cost per Unit']

result = milp(
    c=-df['Profit per Unit'],
    integrality=1,
    bounds=Bounds(lb=0),
    constraints=LinearConstraint(
        # 150 - (x1 + x2 + x3) >= 0
        A=(1, 1, 1), ub=150,
    ),
)
assert result.success

df['Units'] = result.x
df['Total'] = df['Units'] * df['Profit per Unit']
print(df)

          Sale Price  Cost per Unit  Profit per Unit  Units     Total
Products                                                             
TV Set          5000           4000             1000  150.0  150000.0
Stereo          3000           2000             1000    0.0       0.0
Speakers        2000           1500              500    0.0       0.0

